# AngularJS stream audio from PHP server

Tags: php, angularjs, audio, blob, audio-streaming

Due to CORS and authentication with third-party server, I cannot load audio file directly from angularJS and has to do it from PHP backend. Here is my PHP server code to serve the audio file downloaded from the third-party server:

```
header('Pragma: public');   // required
header('Content-Type: audio/mpeg');
header('Content-length: ' . filesize($file));
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
header('Content-Disposition: filename="' . basename($file));
header('X-Pad: avoid browser bug');
header('Cache-Control: no-cache');
$len = readfile($file);
exit();
```

Here is my angularJS client code:

```
var blob = new Blob([response], { type: 'audio/mpeg' });
var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
var audio = new Audio(url);
audio.play();
```

However it fails with the exception message:

```
DOMException: Failed to load because no supported source was found.
```

Any advice and insight is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're just creating an Audio object with the response anyway, there's no reason for you to have to do what you're doing.

Instead of downloading the whole response, creating a Blob out of it, and an object URL, just use the URL you're requesting in the first place.  Not only will you get some nice efficient handling of streaming data, you'll be able to play while the download is running, *and* you won't need CORS... an "opaque" response is fine.

Comment: Hi, there are restrictions from the third-party server. Firstly, it doesn't allow CORS. Secondly, it requires JWT. So it's quite a challenge to do it from javascript. Therefore, the video is downloaded from PHP code then it is served to the javascript.

Comment: @KokHowTeh You don't need CORS, as I said.  If you want to do the signing server-side, do so, and have your PHP script do a redirect to the actual media.  Then you don't have to waste the resources and bandwidth.

Comment: What do you mean? This is what I am trying to do: https://developer.nexmo.com/voice/voice-api/guides/record-calls-and-conversations - Make a GET request using your JWT for authentication in order to retrieve the recording from recording_url. Thanks.

Comment: @KokHowTeh Post a new question with your actual server-side PHP code, drop me a link to it, and I'll answer it.  In short, it's very simple.  Instead of downloading that MP3 with PHP, just redirect to it once you've signed the URL.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46231328/angularjs-stream-audio-from-php-server-2