# AngularJS stream audio from PHP server 2

Tags: javascript, php, audio, jwt

I have the following PHP code which authenticate to a third-party server using JWT and download the recorded audio from the server and then it serves the .mp3 to javascript which constructs an Audio object to playback the audio. How to do this more efficiently?

```
use Lcobucci\JWT\Builder;
use Lcobucci\JWT\Signer\Key;
use Lcobucci\JWT\Signer\Rsa\Sha256;
private function generate_jwt() {
    $dev = preg_match("/blah.blah.com/", $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]);
    $jwt = false;
    date_default_timezone_set('UTC');    //Set the time for UTC + 0
    //$key = file_get_contents($keyfile);  //Retrieve your private key
    $key = $dev ? self::DEV_KEY : self::PRODUCTION_KEY;
    $id = $dev ? self::DEV_ID : self::PRODUCTION_ID;
    $signer = new Sha256();
    $privateKey = new Key($key);
    $jwt = (new Builder())->setIssuedAt(time() - date('Z')) // Time token was generated in UTC+0
        ->set('application_id', $id) // ID for the application you are working with
        ->setId( base64_encode( mt_rand (  )), true)
        ->sign($signer,  $privateKey) // Create a signature using your private key
        ->getToken(); // Retrieves the JWT
    return $jwt;
}
public function playback($url) {
    $response = "";
    if (!empty($url)) {
        //Create your JWT
        $jwt = $this->generate_jwt();
        //Add the JWT to your headers
        $headers =  array('Content-Type: application/json', "Authorization: Bearer " . $jwt);
        $ch = curl_init();
        //Make a request to $recording_url
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
        $response = curl_exec($ch);
        $file = __TMPDIR__ . basename($url).".mp3";
        file_put_contents($file, $response);
        header('Pragma: public');   // required
        header('Content-Type: audio/mpeg');
        header('Content-length: ' . filesize($file));
        header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
        header('Content-Disposition: filename="' . basename($file));
        header('X-Pad: avoid browser bug');
        header('Cache-Control: no-cache');
        $len = readfile($file);
    } else
        error_log(__FILE__." ".__FUNCTION__." ".__LINE__.": Invalid url! ".$url);
}
```

Comment: Ah, I see the issue now... they're not letting you sign your URLs...  that's unfortunate.  I guess you'll be stuck with streaming the response, still proxying.  In any case, yes, you can avoid that intermediary file... the last time I did cURL streaming in PHP, I used multicurl.  It should be possible to do it without it though.

Comment: More unfortunate is the HTMLAudioElement constructor does not take byte stream as input parameter but a URL. I use Blob and build a URL out of it but still bump into the following error: 

DOMException: Failed to load because no supported source was found. 

What do I miss?

Comment: You can give it the URL of your PHP script though... no need to do more than that.  You can even support `Rage` requests with your PHP script.  Don't download the whole thing and make a blob.  Also, you *can* use a stream with MediaSource Extensions, but there's absolutely zero reason to do that here.

Comment: My PHP script file contains a class with other properties and member functions. I don't understand what you mean with new Audio("path_to_script.php"); Can you provide more details please? Thanks.

Comment: Use the exact same URL you're using to access this data in the first place...  look, your PHP script is echoing out the audio data.  Instead of using XHR or whatever it is that you're doing to get that audio data into a Blob client-side, just use the URL for your PHP script.

Comment: You mean the audio source URL? No, it doesn't work. It gets 401 Unauthorized error. :-( I did it in the XHR return code.

Comment: No, the URL of your PHP script.  If their server doesn't support CORS, you can't pass the extra Authorization header.  Most services like that enable a way to sign a URL so the URL can be loaded client-side.  In that case, you would sign the URL with your PHP script and redirect the client there... but this service doesn't do that.  So, all you can do is proxy the data like you're doing... but put the URL of your PHP script in when you instantiate the audio player.

Comment: Just tried and get this exception: "DOMException: Failed to load because no supported source was found."

Comment: Show the full client-side code, as well as a network capture.